# Xcode 6.2 beta version does not the list of iOS Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

Xcode 6.2 beta version does not the list of iOS Devices. It only shows the iOS Device.[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window->Devices`. There is a list of Simulators on the left.

If that list has some simulators, but they aren't showing up, click them and then click the Gear icon in the lower-left of the window and select *Show in Run Destinations Menu*.

If that list doesn't have the simulators you need, click the Plus button in the lower-left. There are a bunch of built-in ones you can choose from a drop down. Or you can create your own custom simulator.

If you're missing them all, I don't know any way to re-add all the defaults. You may just need to add each individually.

Answer (score -1):

reconnect your device or reboot xcode / system

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Stonz2 I believe you are incorrect it does provide an answer to the question even if its a wrong answer it is still an answer. The reason it is an answer is because it actually attempts to answer the question and it isn't just a link or asking for additional information or any other obvious comment. So I believe you are incorrect just because it is wrong doesn't mean it is a comment

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `iOS Device`
you need to upgrade your `iOS Device` i.e. iPhone, iPad.

And for simulators you can download the rest simulators. from downloads section in Xcode preferences.